# Changing Probabilty Values if Stahe Name changes

Tags: salesforce

I have created the custom Opportunity page. How can I bind Probability with Stage Name. I have used Ajax but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Setup > App Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Fields.  Click the "Stage" link in the Opportunity Standard Fields section.  You'll be taken to a page where you can setup your sales stages and assign a probability to each stage name.
2. Go to Setup > App Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Sales Processes.  Here you can create/edit your sales process to use the stages you setup in step 1.
3. Go to Setup > App Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Record Types.  Here you can associate your sales process from Step 2 with the right opportunity record type.

Search for "sales processes" in the [online help](http://www.salesforce.com/help) for more information